# Energy Conversion

Tags: android, unit-conversion

I have taken this code from an example but I don't know how to calculate the value to Base Unit.
This is the code for converting energy:

```
public enum U_EnergyConverter implements UnitConverter {
energy_calories {
    @Override
    public double toBaseUnit(double amount) {
        return amount;
    }

},
energy_joules {
    @Override
    public double toBaseUnit(double amount) {
        return amount * 4.19;
    }
},
energy_kilocalories {
    @Override
    public double toBaseUnit(double amount) {
        return amount * 0.001;
    }

};
public abstract double toBaseUnit(double amount);

public double toUnit(double baseUnitAmount) {
    return baseUnitAmount * (1 / (toBaseUnit(1)));
}
```

The Amounts I used in the code above are giving me wrong result. And I don't know from which source I can get the exact value for unit-conversion!!

Appreciate any help

**Update:**
This is the mass unit code which is working very well:

```
public enum MassConverter implements UnitConverter {
mass_g {
    @Override
    public double toBaseUnit(double amount) {
        return amount;
    }

},
mass_kg {
    @Override
    public double toBaseUnit(double amount) {
        return amount * 1000.00;
    }

},
mass_oz {
    @Override
    public double toBaseUnit(double amount) {
        return amount * 28.3495231;
    }

},
mass_lb {
    @Override
    public double toBaseUnit(double amount) {
        return amount * 453.59237;
    }

};
public abstract double toBaseUnit(double amount);

public double toUnit(double baseUnitAmount) {
    return baseUnitAmount * (1 / (toBaseUnit(1)));
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `The Amounts I used are not giving me the right result.` be more explicit. give specific examples.

Comment: for example when I convert the 15 kilo calories to calories its giving me 62802.0 which is wrong it suppose to give me 15000 calories.

Comment: post the code you use to obtain that result

Comment: sorry I meant the wrong result.

Comment: First code what I posted above giving me wrong result. but the second code working well.

Comment: no, post the actual code you use to obtain 62802.0. (probably something along the lines of `U_EnergyConverter.energy_kilocalories.toBaseUnit(15)`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change like this:

```
energy_kilocalories {
    @Override
    public double toBaseUnit(double amount) {
        return amount * 1000;
    }

};
```

`toBaseUnit` should return value in calories given the value in those units (such as joules, kilocalories etc). This is what the correct example does. Yours does the opposite.

Comment: its a simple converter from - to calories, kilocalories and joules. I mean to convert each to another.

Comment: I've updated my answer, sorry